# How to access Mongodb in AWS EC2 Ubuntu from my laptop

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've found problem that I cannot access my MongoDB hosted in AWS EC2 Ubuntu.

I did

```
#network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
#bindIp: 127.0.0.1

security:
  authorization: 'enabled'
```

, restart MongoDb and open

```
Netword & Security -> Security Groups -> Inbound tab -> Edit button.
Make a new Custom TCP on port 27017, Source: Anywhere, 0.0.0.0/0
```

of Security Group. But when I tried to access like `mongo -u user -p mypassword 52.221.226.195/mydb` and found following error showing that connection refused. Please help me how to solve it.

```
2019-04-17T15:57:58.321+0630 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: what happens if you ssh into the instance and connect locally? did you apply the security group to the instance? try to bind on 0.0.0.0 as well

Comment: See also [`bind_ip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-bind-ip) in the core documentation. The default ( i.e commented out like you have ) is `localhost` only. Please also note that database adminstration and configuration questions should be asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com instead. Just as is mentioned in the tag info for mongodb. Networking ( i.e AWS security groups etc ) questions can be asked on https://serverfault.com

Comment: @tvgriek I've found solution. Many thanks.

Comment: @NeilLunn yap, I've got it.